# JQuery Loop Clone

Tags: jquery, loops, clone

Trying to get my 1 table row to automatically clone exactly 24 times and then get the "add row +" button to clone additional.

Example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/CzZxf/17/

```
var uniqueIds = $("#math-table tr").length;
$("#button").click(function(){
var $thisRow = $(this).closest("tr"),
$clone = $thisRow.removeClass().clone(),             // Clone row
$inputs = $clone.find("input").val("").removeClass();
uniqueIds++; //Increment ID
$inputs[0].id = "A" + uniqueIds;
$inputs[1].id = "B" + uniqueIds;
$inputs[2].id = "C" + uniqueIds;


$thisRow.after($clone);                    
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding `.closest`, it works similarly to `.parents`.

I fixed the traversing to find last `tr` here: http://jsfiddle.net/CzZxf/19/

`var $thisRow = $("#math-table tr:last-child")`

Comment: You are right.  Thanks!  Where would I add the loop code to clone 24 times with my unique IDs on each?

Comment: @user1040259 `var l = 24;

while( l-- ) {
   $("#button").trigger("click" );
}` http://jsfiddle.net/CzZxf/22/

Comment: @user1040259 the code I changed is in the answer :P ( I also pressed "tidy up" in jsfiddle to fix formatting) and the loop is pretty self explanatory

Comment: Hi Esailija, Might it be possible to use your example above and not include $("#button").trigger("click"); in the loop?  I'd like to turn this into a function and pass different button names to it. Basically the loop doesn't work without a proper name.  Maybe I'm confused.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using templates than using clone. See my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CzZxf/25/)** here,

Below addRow function will add a new row to the table.

```
var rowTmpl = '<tr>' +
         '<td><input type="text" id="A{ID}" name="A" value=""></td>' +
         '<td><input type="text" id="B{ID}" name="B" value=""></td>' +
         '<td><input type="text" id="C{ID}" name="C" readonly="readonly" tabIndex="-1" value=""></td>' +
         '</tr>';

function addRow () {    
    var rowCount = $('#math-table tbody tr').length;

    //modify template
    var addRow = rowTmpl.replace (/{ID}/g, rowCount);

    //append to the tbody
    $('#math-table tbody').append(addRow);
}
```